# shellscript iterate through letters

Tags: linux, shell

I need to iterate from c to k alphabetically in shellscript, the attempt below failed, how do I do it properly?

```
for((i='c';i<'k';i++))
do
  echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one works in my shell (Bash 3.0+):

```
for c in {c..k}
do
  echo $c
done
```

Comment: This goes from {a..z} whereas the question asked for {c..k}.

Comment: yeah, I know. just change to c..k

Comment: I wonder why my correct answer which was posted earlier didn't get accepted.  Oh well.  I've edited your answer for you.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in shell (not bash)?

Answer (score 2):

This will work in bash at least:

```
for i in {c..k}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in shell (not bash)?

Comment: @JakubP: What is "shell (not bash)"?  Korn shell?  Zsh?  Fish?  Dash?

Comment: I mean shell as sh. it's always a problem to search for shell scripts, as I haven't found any specific name for it such as bash, ksh, zsh - those are unique. And when one types shell, then it's confusing :-)

Comment: @JakubP: There is no "sh."  There are implementations like the ones I listed.  `sh` is not a specific thing, but rather a cluster of related things.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are not asking for bashisms specifically, here are some alternatives without them.

Simple:

```
for c in c d e f g h i j k; do
    echo $c
done
```

Avoiding the need to list all the characters:

```
s=$(printf %d "'c")
e=$(printf %d "'k")
i=$s
while [ $i -le $e ]; do
    c=$(printf \\$(printf %o $i))
    echo $c
    i=$((i+1))
done
```